# Commiting a transaction at the end of loop iteration. Rollback otherwise

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

I have a list of orders. Every each of them needs to be fully processed. There are several operations to be done on each order.

The sample order processing looks like:

1. validate the buyer
2. validate the seller
3. create historical order (separate entity) for buyer and the seller
4. update the buyer
5. update the seller
6. save historical orders from pt. 3
7. send notifications
8. update order state to 'completed'

Now with my list of orders, I'm looping through with for loop. How do I ensure the transaction commit is done at the end of current iteration? I do want to avoid the situation where steps 4 & 5 are commited and  then there's some exception while executing save in step 6. I cannot stop the application, but need to set order's state to 'rejected' and continue processing. What I really want to achive is:

```
for (Order o : orders){
try{
    doStep1;
    doStep2;
    doStep3;
    doStep4;
    doStep5;
    doStep6;
    doStep7;
    doStep8('completed');
    commitAllUpdates&Saves;
} catch (Exception e){
    doStep8('rejected');
}
```

Help.

Comment: if you add a finally block after the catch, this is guaranteed to be called. You'll need a flag, though, to let it know if it is an error or not. It's try {...} catch (Exception e) {...} finally {...}

Comment: Here's a quick suggestion, but are you unable to commit all updates outside of the for loop? - I'm just thinking of doing one large transactions, rather than loads of tiny ones, obviously this depends on your setup & requirements, etc.